# Nasm / Assembly How to write this pseudocode

Tags: assembly, while-loop, nasm

I want to write a while loop that calculates the greatest common divisor of 2 numbers.

This is the pseudo code

```
Euclid(a, b)
while (b != 0)
{
r = a mod b
a = b
b = r
}
return a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` does not take two arguments.  It divides `edx:eax` by the argument if it's a 32-bit value.  See http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html for example.

A quick fix would be (could be improved but this is a start)

```
_while:
    xor edx,edx
    mov eax,ebx
    div ecx
    mov ebx,ecx
    mov ecx, edx
    cmp ecx,0
    ; etc
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem with the while loop but now i got a segmentation fault(core dumped) after I input the numbers. I will give you the code of the main program maybe you find the error :(

Comment: the main program is now in the question

Comment: @l2iisk you're missing 2 `pop` in your asm_main

Comment: pop just loads something from the stack and moves the stack pointer.  Where you pop it to matter only if you care about the value.  Your program does not seem to care.  You can pop it to whatever register you want

Answer (score 0):

DIV only receives a single operand. It divides edx:eax by the operand and the remainder is in edx.

Comment: For those who are "into it", there's some discussion of GCD code here: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/asmexample.html - doesn't use `div` :)